# Replace IIS 403 with 404 for Directory Listing

Tags: iis, iis-6, iis-7.5

Is it possible to have IIS (6 or 7.5) return a `404 Not Found` (instead of `403 Forbidden`) when a disallowed directory listing is requested?

A security scanning service I use thinks the 403 is revealing something "potentially sensitive", when in fact it's just not a valid URL. My workaround is to drop a `default.aspx` into each directory that returns an empty 404 page, but there has to be a better way...

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Configure a custom error message for 403.14 to run a simple ASP page that returns a 404 response code.  403.14 is the Status and subcode used for 'Directory listing denied'.